# Deploying Google Cloud Functions with TensorFlow as a dependency

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to use Google Cloud Functions to deploy a keras model saved in JSON (including weights in HDF5) with tensorflow as backend.

The deployment succeed when I don't specify tensorflow in requirements.txt. Although when testing the function in GCP, I get the error message specifying that tensorflow could not be found.

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
No module named 'tensorflow'
```

First, I find it quite strange that Google doesn't provide environments with tensorflow pre-installed.

But now if I specify tensorflow in requirements.txt, deployment fails with the error message

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: 
code=3, message=Build failed: USER ERROR:
`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
 Could not find a version that satisfies the 
requirement tensorflow (from -r /dev/stdin (line 5)) 
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow (from -r 
/dev/stdin (line 5))
```

Is there a way I can get tensorflow on Cloud Functions or Google deliberately blocks the install to get us to use ML Engine?

Comment: FYI, [Tensorflow now supports Python 3.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517#issuecomment-461910761)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** [Tensorflow 1.13.1 now supports Python 3.7.](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517#issuecomment-461910761)

---

**Previous answer:**

There isn't currently a way to use `tensorflow` on Google Cloud Functions.

However, it's not because Google is deliberately blocking it: the [`tensorflow` package](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files) only provides built distributions for CPython 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6, but [the Cloud Functions Python runtime is based on Python version 3.7.0](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime), so `pip` (correctly) can't find any compatible distributions.

There are currently [some compatibility issues with TensorFlow and Python 3.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517), but once that is fixed, `tensorflow` should be installable on Google Cloud Functions. For now though, you'll have to use ML Engine.

Comment: thank you so much for this info which was nowhere else available! Now this finally explains why Google Cloud Function cannot import Keras with TensorFlow backend...